# Print top terms per cluster in AffinityPropagation in Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have very simple AffinityPropagation model function for some text clustering:

```
def fit_affprop(X, damping=0.5):
affprop = AffinityPropagation(affinity='euclidean', damping=damping)
affprop.fit_predict(X)
clustering = collections.defaultdict(list)
for idx, label in enumerate(affprop.labels_):
    clustering[label].append(idx)
terms = vec.get_feature_names()
print(terms)
print(affprop.cluster_centers_indices_)
```

The question is, which I haven't been able to figure out, how to print out the top terms per cluster? I have tried modifying the approach I have for k-means:

```
print("Top terms per cluster:")
order_centroids = km_model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vec.get_feature_names()
for i in range(clusters):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i, end='')
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind], end='')
```

argsort gives an error, since the cluster centers are of a different form than k-means.

Comment: what is the shape of affprop.cluster_centers_indices_?

Comment: 1xn vector where n is the number of clusters. i.e. [0 1 2 3]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an obvious equivalent.

You could compare the cluster centers yourself. That is straightforward and should work okay, but the center does not play any particular role in AP clustering.

Or you could look at the cluster representative, which makes more sense from AP. But as this is a single document, and won't actually give you quantitative information about importance of terms (but actually, not does k-means...) You need to get the vector for the *index* that you have so far.